# Trying to fopen en fwrite vcard content trigger by another page?

Tags: php

So i have a page lookup.php?id=xxxx which generates a vcard and force download the generated vcard. This one works

Now i am trying another page lookup2.php which holds an input fields which reads the id and refresh the page with the id value and should save the vcard. 
This one doesn't work as the vcard content is not right. When i watch the content it seems the whole html is written after

> END:VCARD

Both php files include the same vcard.class.php, here is the class function which writes the content

```
public function SaveVcard() {

    $handel = @fopen($this->saveTo . "/" . $this->fileName . ".vcf", "w");
    //$contentCard = createVcard();
  //  $write = @fwrite($handel, $contentCard, strlen($this->vcard));
   $write = @fwrite($handel, $this->vcard, strlen($this->vcard));
    @fclose($handel);
    return $write ? true : false;
}
```

Now i guess $this->vcard in my second setup writes the whole html code of lookup2.php after END:VCARD

This js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

                    $('#scanTheBarcode').focus();

                    $('#scanTheBarcode').keyup(function(e) {
                        scanBarcode = $(this);
                        // if Enter key was pressed, send the barcode to backend 
                        if ((e.keyCode == 13) && (scanBarcode.val().length > 2)) {
                            //TMP store value

                            $('#status').html(scanBarcode.val());
                            var scancode = scanBarcode.val();

                            var url = 'http://www.example.com/test/lookup2.php';

                            window.location = url+"?id="+scancode;
                            $('#scanTheBarcode').val('');
                            $('#scanTheBarcode').focus();
                        }

                    });


                });
```

Also on lookup2.php

```
include('vcard.class.php');
if($_GET['id']) {
$vCardDetails = generateSQL($_REQUEST['id']);

$vCardDetails["saveTo"] = "vcards";
$codeContents = new VCard($vCardDetails);
$newVCard = $codeContents->createVcard();
echo $newVCard;//just testing
$codeContents->SaveVcard();

$codeContents->DownloadVcard();
}
```

and in vcard.class.php

```
    // Function create vCard
        function createVcard() {

            // we building raw data 
            $this->vcard = 'BEGIN:VCARD' . "\n";
            $this->vcard .= 'VERSION:2.1' . "\n";
            $this->vcard .= 'N:' . $this->lname .  "\n";
            $this->vcard .= 'FN:' . $this->fname . "\n";
            $this->vcard .= 'ORG:' . $this->company . "\n";
            $this->vcard .= 'TITLE:' . $this->title . "\n";

            $this->vcard .= 'TEL;WORK;VOICE:' . $this->phone . "\n";
            $this->vcard .= 'ADR;TYPE=work;' .
                    'LABEL="' . $this->addressLabel . '":'
                    . $this->postal . ';'
                    //. $addressExt . ';'
                    . $this->address . ' ' . $this->no . ';'
                    . $this->place . ';'
                    . $this->postal . ';'
                    . $this->land
                    . "\n";

            $this->vcard .= 'EMAIL:' . $this->email . "\n";

            $this->vcard .= 'END:VCARD';


            // Set Vcard to Private Vcard
            //$this->vcard=$vcard;
            return $this->vcard; 
    }
```

Comment: How and where is the `$this->vcard` property populated? That code doesn't tell us anything about the content.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is populate in the vcard class, i added the class function createvCard

Comment: ok i think i found a workable solution. In lookup2.php i had to put the html code in the php else statement part. So it reads `if($_GET['id']) { ......$codeContents->DownloadVcard();
} else { ...all the page html }`